# include/net/sch_generic.h:199: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘psched_time_t’

Tags: c

Hi there i am having problem with psched_time_t defined in the struct below it gives the identifier expected error of which I thought that error happens when the corresponding header file is not included and I did include it which is #include  and in this file psched_time_t is declared. so what am I doing wrong? please help

```
     #ifndef __NET_SCHED_GENERIC_H
     #define __NET_SCHED_GENERIC_H

     #include <linux/netdevice.h>
     #include <linux/types.h>
     #include <linux/rcupdate.h>
     #include <linux/module.h>
     #include <linux/pkt_sched.h>
     #include <linux/pkt_cls.h>
     #include <net/gen_stats.h>
     #include <net/rtnetlink.h>


    struct agg_queue {
            __be32              dest;
            __u32               currSize;
            __u32               maxSize;
            psched_time_t       timestamp; //this is where the error is
            struct agg_queue    *next;
            struct sk_buff_head skb_head;

            };
```

The file below is net/pkt_sched.h which is where psched_time_t is defined:

```
#ifndef __NET_PKT_SCHED_H
#define __NET_PKT_SCHED_H
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/ktime.h>
#include <net/sch_generic.h>

  struct qdisc_walker {
    int     stop;
    int     skip;
    int     count;
    int     (*fn)(struct Qdisc *, unsigned long cl, struct qdisc_walker *);
```

};

```
#define QDISC_ALIGNTO           64
#define QDISC_ALIGN(len)        (((len) + QDISC_ALIGNTO-1) & ~(QDISC_ALIGNTO-1))

  static inline void *qdisc_priv(struct Qdisc *q)
     {
        return (char *) q + QDISC_ALIGN(sizeof(struct Qdisc));
      }

  typedef u64     psched_time_t;
  typedef long    psched_tdiff_t;

  /* Avoid doing 64 bit divide */
  #define PSCHED_SHIFT                    6
  #define PSCHED_TICKS2NS(x)              ((s64)(x) << PSCHED_SHIFT)
  #define PSCHED_NS2TICKS(x)              ((x) >> PSCHED_SHIFT)

  #define PSCHED_TICKS_PER_SEC            PSCHED_NS2TICKS(NSEC_PER_SEC)
  #define PSCHED_PASTPERFECT              0

  static inline psched_time_t psched_get_time(void)
     {
       return PSCHED_NS2TICKS(ktime_to_ns(ktime_get()));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few #ifdefs/#ifndefs but no #endif anywhere. As you know, each of the former requires one of the latter. Add #endifs where they are needed and you'll get further along.

**EDIT:** The problem is not `psched_time_t` but, as the error message says, something before that line. So where is `maxSize` defined?

Comment: I did not include the whole code, otherwise it does have #endif at the end of the code i just included the portion that gives me problem

Comment: pls somebody help me, i am still stuck